# what is the type of file in git?

Tags: github

I just upload code to Github. I have this file, I can not open it.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking on the text instead of the line?

Comment: What command did you use to upload it?

Answer (score 0):

Github **does not** change the type of file.It keeps the original format in which it was uploaded.Check the size of file on Github to the original.It might be corrupted due to incomplete upload.